# Simple console graphics, GUI or interface from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ncurses

I would like to spruce up the output of a Bash shell script by doing some simple, [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)-like console displays.

For instance, I would like to show a percentage value increasing as some activity completes. I can do this by outputting each percent value on a new line, for example,

```
0%
1%
2%
... etc. ...
```

But I would prefer to have the text update in place (that is, the script only writes one line of output to show the percent, and then the percent value displayed on that line changes). I know I could use a different scripting language and ncurses, but is there a Bash solution that doesn't incur too much pain. Preferably, I'd like something with wide support across various Unix'es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outputting `\r` will return the cursor to the first column so that you can write over the text already in place. If you need more sophisticated motion than that, `tput` with the various `cu*` capabilities will allow you to move and place the cursor as desired.

Comment: Thanks ignacio. Could you elaborate on the cu* capabilities. I don't know what that is.

Comment: From the `terminfo(5)` man page, they are `cuf1` (cursor right), `cub1` (cursor left), `cuu1` (cursor up), `cud1` (cursor down), and `cup` (cursor move). See the `tput(1)` man page for more details.

Answer (score 2):

For full generality and portability, this would be the [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) package.  The basic `ncurses` build is highly portable; there is also a Gtk+ GUI version called `gdialog`.  You then have the option not only of what you described, but also an actual progress bar widget.

On the simpler side, simply outputting `\r` (use the `printf` utility, or on older commercial Unixes one of `echo -n ...^M` or `echo ... \r\c`) will let you overwrite a line.

Comment: Thanks geekosaur. I saw `dialog` but it didn't seem to be installed by default on my dev Mac OS X system. Is it available by default on most *nix'es?

Comment: +1 for printf. I didn't know that existed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No, but it builds almost everywhere.  As for OS X, there are at least three variants of it in MacPorts (`dialog`, `xdialog`, and `zenity`).

Answer (score 1):

Use ANSI escape codes for using or coloring your cursor.

Here a short example in python (run it with the -u flag for unbuffered because else you wouldn't see the updating):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys

for i in range (10):
    sys.stdout.write ('%d\x1b[1D' % i)
    time.sleep (1)
```

CSInD ('\x1b[1D') moves the cursor n positions to the left. And if you want a colored cursor, just print e.g. '\x1b[1;31m'. Works on almost all shells.

Comment: Thanks Hyperboreus. Good to know about the ANSI escape code options, although for bash, I find the `tput` approach to be less obscure.

Comment: @zlovelady. Yes for this case CSI is perhaps a bit of overkill. But the day you want to do weird and eye-souring stuff on the console, remember the ANSI codes.